# bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am trying create a Zuul Api gateway for my microservices.
It also has the eureka disovery client.

Here is the application class

ZuulServerApplication.java

```java
package com.ftr.zuul;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ZuulServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ftr</groupId>
    <artifactId>ZuulServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ZuulServer</name>
    <description>Zuul API Gateway for FTR</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

I am getting the following error while trying to run the application.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field optionalArgs in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' in your configuration.
```

It is working fine without the Zuulserver but when I add the zuul dependency I get this error.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I got same issue with Spring Boot 3.0 even without Zuul. Any one has solution for this

Answer (score 3):

Reverting back to Spring Boot 2.7.7 is the only thing that has worked for me so far, so if you're able to do that then it's probably the easiest solution:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I realise this isn't a great long-term fix, though. I'll keep looking and update this if I find anything better.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. It got resolved by adding below two properties in application.yaml

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone:  http://localhost:8761/eureka
    instance:
      preferIpAddress:  true
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. My problem was that org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient was on the class path.

Comment: JerseyClient was being included though com.github.docker-java. Unfortunately I need docker-java in my project and am still looking for a workaround